# How to create oscilloscope type display using QCustomPlot

Tags: qt, graphics, graph, qcustomplot

In oscilloscope display we have two zero lines and axes are at the middle. I have to display two graphs, one in the upper region and other in the lower region, something similar to the image in this link:
http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse467/05wi/tools/oscopefordummies/OscopeBasics.html

Answer (score -1):

For scientific plots you can use [Qwt](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/index.html) with Qt it will be better than going through QGraphicsView and managing grid and all through code. You can add plugin of Qwt to desgner too. 
Here is useful link
[to add Qwt in designer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.6/adding-plugins.html)

Comment: I have already used QCustomPLot, does QWT offer any advantage, is it faster.

Comment: I haven't used it in my application directly but I used a library MITK which uses Qwt for their widgets and those were fine for me.